# Can my bike support a kickstand?

Tags: commuter, reference, kickstand

I recently purchased a 2015 Salsa Vaya 3 and am mostly using it for commuting. I can't seem to find any reliable source of information that explicitly says if I can or cannot support a kickstand.  Does anybody know if this is possible?

[image: Salsa Vaya]

Comment: I'd contact Salsa, but I'd guess their official word will be no.

Comment: It is a steel touring bike so most likely yes but Salsa may not endorse that.

Comment: Is there a bridge welded to the chainstays, right behind the bottom bracket?   If not you may be stuck with either a rear axle kickstand or possibly a chainstay-clamp kickstand.

Comment: @Criggie, I'm pretty new to bike anatomy, so I've uploaded a picture.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Busch A little help, but I was asking about the area in front of the rear tyre, straight behind the pedal's axle.

Comment: Made the title more generic as it is a good reference question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are at least four different places you can mount a kickstand.

[image: Vaya 2015]

From left to right:

1. **Orange arrow:** Rear axle kickstand. These come in one-sided and two-sided varieties. The one sided are not that stable and since your bike has what looks like a child carrier, I wouldn't recommended it. Axle mount kickstands are very popular on children's bicycles:

[image: One sided]
The two sided are very heavy but are very stable. These are very cheap but don't fit on many derailleur bikes as they foul the  rear derailleur. They are popular with [IGH](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internally-geared-hub) cargo bikes and so-called "mom bikes" (in Japan) as they will not tip over under load:

[image: Two sided axle]

2. **Lime-green arrow:** Chainstay mount are inexpensive but not that stable - although better than rear-axle. They look much like the rear-axle mounts. The most important thing to match is the diameter of your chainstay (the horizontal bar that my limegreen arrow is pointing to) and the clamp of the mount. However, in your case you have a rear disc brake and you need to make sure your chainstay mount won't interfere with the brake cable (the brake cable should be able to pass over your kickstand mount bracket without problem, but a particularly thick mounting bracket might interfer). Better chainstay kickstands also mount to the seat stay as that provides more leverage against the kickstand torquing or rotating on just the chainstay or bending the chainstay under weight. Note this design also allows a passthru for the rear disc brake cable. However, there are more fit issues if you have nonstandard chainstays or seatstays or rear triangle design, which can lead to complications if you have rear suspension for example.

[image: chainstay kickstand]

3. **Red-arrow:** Chainstay-bottom bracket bridge mount: This is the traditional kickstand mounting place for many bikes -- and many bikes have a welded bracket for a kickstand here (the photo here is taken of the bottom of the bike):

[image: bridge kickstand mount]

Without a bracket, you have to be sure that there's enough space behind your bottom bracket (where your pedals attach) and the tire for the kickstand. Most if not all kickstands will come with bridge mounting plates/clamps and you do need to observe the mounting bolt torque limits as too little torque will cause the kickstand to slip while too much can crush the chainstays. And you should avoid the clamps if you have a carbon frame bike (your Vaya isn't carbon fiber so you have nothing to worry about).

There are both singlesided and double-sided  bridge mount kickstand varieties. As usual, the double-sided kickstands are more stable than singlesided:

[image: Double kickstand]

4. **Blue arrow:** Trekking bikes or bikes carrying trailers will occasionally use top-tube stands. These are not very useful for commuting. While trekking, many people will just use sticks or their hiking poles.

[image: Trekking stand]

<sub>Fine print: One thing to note about almost all kickstands is that they will clank around if you hop curbs or take jumps. Bridge and chainstay kickstands can also get in the way of your pedal or feet if you don't check clearances, as well as hit curbs and other obstacles if you're not careful. My bridgemount double folding kickstand almost hits my disk brake rotor on my folding ebike and will limit my ability to move to a larger rotor.  Larger double sided axle mount stands can affect your cornering ability. Your mileage may vary, buy from a store that'll let you return it if it doesn't fit.</sub>

to;dr: The best option for your particular bike varies on what your needs are. If you're carrying kids on a rear seat, you may want a double-sided axle mount or bridge mount. If you're commuting, you may want the simplicity of a single-sided bridge or chainstay mount kickstand.

Comment: It looks like I don't need to write that canonical question on kickstands after all, as you've covered them all here, and the question has a good general title.

Comment: One downside of double BB/chainstay bridge kickstands is that they foul on some bike racks (which also seems to loosen the bolt). Riding off kerbs at a fine angle is a bad idea too as they can hit the ground before the back wheel. If you don't have a bridge plate you need to be sure you don't crush the chainstays when mounting.

Comment: Thanks Chris H, I incorporated many of your comments into my answer.

Comment: I think the main thing someone asking this question is usually after is guidance on determining whether they can safely clamp a kickstand across their chainstays, and this answer doesn't really offer that, other than to say don't do it on carbon. It's not as simple as that, and people mess up their frames thinking it is. I read this question as whether Vayas are likely to have the same kickstand issues as LHTs. You also don't get into when you would you use a top-plate kickstands (ie Greenfield KS2), a model intended for frame plates (KS3), low clearance solutions (Greenfield Retro Kit).

Comment: @NathanKnutson - I wrote this as a 'generic' answer. You might want to write your own Vaya-specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a wide variety of kickstands available, my guess is you would likely be able to find one that would fit. If the frame doesn't have a crossbar and hole behind the bottom bracket for a center mount kickstand, you could likely use an adjustable rear mount, they make some that are compatible with disc brakes and this is likely what you would need.

Here is an image of one that is adjustable in length and made to be compatible with disc brakes. This particular one attaches to both the chain stay and the seat stay bars and has a curve in the mounts which is intended to clear the disc brake caliper. The leg also extends to work with several different wheel sizes.

[image]

I have also seen one or two that were described as axle mount but do not know much about them, although that sounds a little sketchy to me.

I will also add that most "serious" cyclists tend to remove kickstand if the bike comes with them as they are rarely used and add extra weigh, in addition to being prone to coming loose and or snagging on road/trail debris.

Comment: This post was very helpful, can you tell me if this will fit the picture above?  Not familiar enough with bike anatomy to know really :)

Comment: The OP specifically mentions commuting. Lots of the serious bike commuters in my community do have kickstands. There are lots of ways to be a serious cyclist.

Comment: Many serious cyclists *do* like having kickstands, especially after spending too much time trying to find a place to park their bike while all their "less serious" friends just drop their kickstands and walk off...

Comment: what's a "serious" cyclist? (what sort of serious cyclist buys a bike that comes with a kickstand, and then removes it? what cyclists are we talking about, here? what sort of bike do they have?)

Answer (score 0):

The kickstands from decathlon do the job. I like to have the chainstay 500 type on my kona sutra. Adds 400 grams of weight but that’s not a problem to me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Will that fit on the bike in the question?